# Geting version of python executable from a script

Tags: python, subprocess, version

I have different python versions installed (from source) on my server. Now I'd like to be able to get the version of a python executable from another python script (running another python version).

I know I can do it from the shell with `path/to/python -V`. But I'd like to do it from a script, like:

```
command = ' '.join([pythonpath, '-V'])
output = subprocess.check_output( command, shell=True )
print output
```

But in this case *check_output* does not work as expected: the output is shown in the terminal but does not go into the variable *output*.

Comment: What is `pythonpath`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Since it is a variable, I belive it must be the path to one of his Python commands

Comment: yes exactly, it's the path to one of the python executables

Comment: In the meantime I found a workaround here: https://linuxconfig.org/check-python-version. So the command is `/path/to/python /path/to/check_python_script.py`. With this command check_output works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cmd = '/usr/local/bin/python2'
    param = '-V'

    process = Popen([cmd, param], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    process.wait()

    # be aware, the order should be out, err for shell tools, but python reply shows in err, out, i've no idea why

    err, out = process.communicate()

    print out
```

**Output**:

> Python 2.7.15

You can see source code [here](https://github.com/caa06d9c/Examples/blob/master/Python/tools/basic/get_python2_version/run.py).

Comment: It doesn't work for me, same problem as with my own initial script: the result of `out = process.communicate()[0].splitlines()` is printed but the variable **out** is an empty list. Maybe it works on Python 3, I'm working on 2.7.15.